# What can cause iOS Safari touch event to ignore top layer div and hit layer underneath?

Tags: ios, css

I have what should be a fairly straightforward CSS top menu that shows itself on hover.  It is just a series of anchor tags, each of which lives inside a list item of an unordered list.  The containing div has the following CSS

```
div.navigation .menuContainer .menu li:hover .mdrop_column {display: block;}

div.navigation .menuContainer .menu li .mdrop_column {position: absolute;
text-align: left;
padding: 6px 4px 7px 0px;
border: 1px solid #666;
background: white;
width: 170px;
z-index: 999999;
display: none;
line-height:12px;}
```

This shows up properly on top of other page content in all browsers and devices. However, in iOS safari, touch events only register for the first few items, after which (when it starts to overlap with the main page content) it will still highlight the link as if it has been clicked in the menu, but then not actually go to the link.  If there is something clickable, such as a different link, underneath the menu it will click there instead.

Strangely enough, a long press will still provide an "open" option for the link in the menu, that actually does work if pressed.  Clearly that isn't good enough.

This menu works in all other browsers I have tested (IE 8+, FF, Chrome, safari desktop, chrome (android) ) and only has this odd behaviour in iOS.

The div it's overlapping has the following CSS styles (taken from the inspector, applied through various classes):

```
width: 100%;
outline: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-weight: inherit;
font-style: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: inherit;
color: inherit;
display: block;
```

I am starting to think it might actually not be a CSS thing, or at least not directly related to the overlapping div.  There might be something between the the divs, some CSS or tag, that causes this issue.

If anyone has seen this issue before, or thinks they might know what I should be looking for... I have been banging my head on this for a day, so fresh ideas would be much appreciated.